# Colorize table name in Graphviz entity-relationship diagram

Tags: graphviz

This Graphviz code:

```
digraph models_diagram {

  graph[rankdir=LR, overlap=false, splines=true]
  struct1 [shape=record, label="Table 0|<f0> ID: integer|<f1> TABLE_1_ID: integer"]
  struct2 [shape=record, label="Table 1|<f0> ID: integer|<f1> NAME: string"]
  struct2:f0 -> struct1:f1;

}
```

Will create this ERD:

[image]

I would like to apply special formatting (e.g. back-ground color; font weight) to each rectangle's header (e.g. "Table 1").

I thought about embedding one shape within another, then I could set `style=filled, color=lightgrey` on one of the shapes, but I can't get the syntax to work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
digraph models_diagram{
    graph[rankdir=LR, overlap=false, splines=true];
    node [shape=record, fontsize=9, fontname="Verdana"];
    edge [style=dashed];
  table0 [shape=none, margin=0, label=<
    <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tr><td bgcolor="lightblue">Table 0</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="0" align="left">ID: integer</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="2" align="left">TABLE_1_ID: integer</td></tr>
    </table>>];
  table1 [shape=none, margin=0, label=<
    <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tr><td bgcolor="lightblue">Table 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="0" align="left">ID: integer</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="1" align="left">NAME: string</td></tr>
    </table>>];
  table1:0 -> table0:2;
}
```

Leads to this:

[image]